# UINavigationBar color has changed after upgrading to latest Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

Recently I've updated my Xcode IDE to the latest to have iOS 7.1 SDK. For some reason, after recompiling my app with the new Xcode **I get this wired `UINavigationBar` background colour**.

I'm using `storyboard` to push the secondary view controller from home screen. The secondary view controller is a static table of settings, also built using `storyboard`, and contains the following code in its `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil;
```

I haven't done any other changes to this screen or any other screens in the app.

This is how it used to look like before:

[image]

This is how it is look like now:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could have caused this?

Cheers,

EDIT: @Leo Natan -

When I'm trying to set the color myself, for example, by replacing this line:

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

with this line:

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

I get this: the red color applied only on the header without the status bar, what can I do?

[image]

Comment: Try to reset (NO then YES) the trunslucent effect ...

Comment: You should set `barTintColor`, not background color.

Comment: @SaifDeen it didn't help

Comment: @LeoNatan setting the <code>barTintColor</code> did nothing. It leaves the entire navigation bar with no background at all (or a transparent one)

Comment: @LeoNatan oh... I see that setting `barTintColor` in addition to `setBackgroundImage` get me the old result I'm expecting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest Xcode comes with iOS7.1 SDK, in which Apple once again changed how the color is calculated. You will have to play again with your color to achieve a similar look in iOS7.1.

Comment: I've edited the question to add another part according to your suggestion. Can you please check?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take another approach. Use the Appearance Proxy in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. Thats how I do it:

```
//Navigationbar
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:lightOrangeColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarAssets-backArrow-iOS7"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarAssets-backArrow-iOS7"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```